# How to get more items from documents using mongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.uafiles.find({"operating_system":"Windows XP"},{"is_pc":"True"})
```

Currently I have a record of 15000 user agent details on a collection.When I'm trying to query, I got only 20 items from the collection.What query would it make me to list the entire items ?

Comment: may change query as `.find({"operating_system":"Windows XP","is_pc":"True"})`. And check `"True"` string or `Boolean true`

Comment: @yogesh this will not work since OP wants to return all documents that match the query.

Comment: @user3100115  I think problem with query because if query return all matched documents then mongo shell default shows `it` to iterate over more results like `has more`

Comment: for example if you do `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = db.collection.count()` in the shell before `db.collection.find()` you have no `it` because it return every document in your collection and that is what OP wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the  `DBQuery.shellBatchSize` attribute value in order to change the number of iteration which basically corresponds to the number of returned document. more info [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#executing-queries)

For example to return the 100 documents use

```js
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 100
```

To return all documents that match your query criteria use:

```js
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = db.uafiles.count({ "operating_system": "Windows XP" }, { "is_pc": "True" })
```

Then:

```js
db.uafiles.find({ "operating_system":"Windows XP" }, { "is_pc": "True" })
```

But why will you want to do that since typing `it` returns the next 20 documents if any.